# vuejs chartjs issue with array displaying multiple data for 1 person

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I have a piechart from chartjs that was displaying data using chartkick.js The issue is, I now want the data to appear on 1 chart. So the chart should show all 3 "scores" for the one Name, but be identified by the different reviewers. Can someone take a look at my array or tell me what needs to be restructured?

```js
function groupBy(list, keyGetter) {
  const map = {};
  list.forEach((item) => {
    const key = keyGetter(item);
    const collection = map[key];
    if (!collection) {
      map[key] = [item];
    } else {
      collection.push(item);
    }
  });
  return map
}


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    field: 'score',
    field2:'reviewer',
    field3:'name',

    People: [{Name: 'Michael John', score:'22',reviewer:'self'}, {Name: 'Michael John', score:'42',reviewer:'friend'}, {Name: 'Michael John', score:'10',reviewer:'lead'}, {Name: 'Zeus Mayho', score:'12',reviewer:'self'}, {Name: 'Zeus Mayho', score:'22',reviewer:'friend'}, {Name: 'Zeus Mayho', score:'30',reviewer:'lead'}] 
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function() {
      this.field = this.field == 'reviewer' 
    }
  },
  computed: {
    rows() {
      let byGroup = groupBy(this.People, it => it[this.field])
      return Object.entries(byGroup).map(en => ([en[0], en[1].length]))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/chart.js@2.7.2/dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-chartkick@0.5.1"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Function:</h2>
  <button @click='toggle'>Toggle</button>
  <h3>By {{field}}</h3>
  <span v-for='row of rows' style='margin:10px;'>{{row[0]}}:{{row[1]}}</span>
  <pie-chart :data="rows" legend="bottom"></pie-chart>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your 3 sets of data ? BTW you have one syntax error

Comment: I meant its the same set of data but there are several objects in the data for each person